# Is there a way to run Rails tests without a Javascript runtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, therubyracer

I'm trying to make my CI pipelines leaner and quicker. I don't have integration tests for my Rails app, so I want to run tests without installing Node or any other JS runtime.

I've tried adding this to my config/test.rb:

```rb
  config.assets.enabled = false
  config.assets.compile = false
```

And also tried setting `test.compile` to `false` in webpacker.yml. However, every time I run `rails test` on CI I get an `ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable` error.

Is there a way to run Rails tests without depending on a JS runtime?